# set the state of the method

Tags: java, swing, enums, jcombobox

in my GUI i have the

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { 
state = new JComboBox(EnumStates.values());
state =(JComboBox)ae.getSource()
state.getSelectedItem() //this returns what I want
```

then I have object of some other class like that uses the EnumStates

```
CallmeClass obj;
```

and when I try to set the state of the enum with the result of the JComboBox like this

```
  obj.setState(state.getSelectedItem());
```

I get compile error

**1. required state but found object**

So my question is `is there a way to make the setState take as argument state.getSelectedItem() withouth changing the return type of the method setState() or re declaring the enums in the gui`. Thanks.

Comment: Try casting state.getSelectedItem() to the required State object

Comment: Show us your code and the exact compiler error message. The three lines of code you're showing already don't make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your declaration for `setState` is seomthing like this:

```
public void setState(State state){
    ...
}
```

The problem is that JComboBox is untyped (at least it was that way until Java7).  So `getSelectedItem()` always returns an object that needs to be casted to your type.  So you can do the cast when you're getting the item:

```
obj.setState((State)state.getSelectedItem());
```

Or you can change your method declaration to object and do your cast there:

```
public void setState(Object state){
    if(state instanceof State){
        State realState = (State)state;
        ...
    }
}
```